# How do I get the number of active users on my django website?

Tags: javascript, django, web-analytics, django-sessions, active-users

I want to display the number of active visitors on my website, I tried using `django-tracking`, `django-active-users` but none of them worked because they are outdated. I am using Django 3.0.8 and all of those modules aren't supported with django3.

I also tried doing this with Google analytics but their real-time reporting API is in limited beta and not open to everyone.
Is there any way I can get this to work using Django active sessions or something?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DailyCount` model which has `date(DateField)`, `active_users(PositiveIntegerField)`.

Then use [celery periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) with a function that is triggered at `hour=0, minute=0`, i.e., every day.

Create a `DailyCount` instance in the triggered function.

---

Whenever a user visits the site for the first time that day, increase `DailyCount.active_users` by 1.